# I made the front end first

Tags: solidity, truffle, react

I'm creating my first app with truffle but I made the front end first... I wanted to replace the client folder with my existing react app but I noticed the App.js file has numerous functions that I may need? What is the best way to import

Comment: I tried moving my components folder to the truffle template and added my code to the Truffle App class but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I use is keep using React folder structure and add the folders and files Truffle requires. Ensure you have "contracts" folder, "migrations" folder with appropriate migrations.js files, and your truffle-config.js file in root.